# Why an’t I seem to produce 8.5 x 11 scans of 8.5 x 11 docs when using Brother scanners?

Tags: documents, scanning, brother-printer

I have 3 scanners – one HP and two Brothers. Neither of the Brother machines can produce a PDF that is exactly 8.5 x11. Sometimes I'll get 8.26 x 10.76 or 8.32 x 10.79 - you get the idea. This creates a problem because I stitch pdfs together using Kofax for e-filing in courts. I can always tell which pages are created with the Brother scanner because they are out of size. Beyond frustrating.

Yesterday I just configured a new Brother ADS-2700W Wireless High-Speed Desktop Document Scanner. This is because my wife's Brother MFC-L3750CDW (a great machine) has the same issue. I also have a new HP M479fdw Printer Scanner Copier in my home office but the scans often come out skewed from the ADF and scanning to my email takes too many steps – I am looking for on-touch default scanning (docs, not photos). I do not need duplex but I do need wireless to send scans to office email address.

I have tried several times to engage Brother Support on this issue and they don’t get it – they keep referring to scans of originals sized other than 8.5 x 11 or tell me that blank portions of the page are not being picked up. Internet blogs suggest unchecking any “crop” features but the Brother ADS-2700W has none that I could find.

I am about to return the new Brother ADS-2700W and pick up either an HP ScanJet Enterprise Flow 5000 or something similar.

Comment: Have you determined (do a test copy with regularly-spaced marks out to the edged) if they are being cropped? I ask because sometimes these one-touch processes are actually reducing the full-sized scan to then fit the 8.5 x 11 scan into the known-printable area of the device (which is usually a multi-function printer). Hard to say because I'd expect any document feeder to require grip margins just like a printer.

Comment: An answer suggested to use WIA. Since TWAIN has three transfer modes (Native, Memory, File), while WIA only has two (Memory, File), try to check which is the transfer mode you are currently using. It is possible that is the Native one and its control could depend from the specific hardware settings.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to fix this problem by switching from the TWAIN scanner to WIA using paperport.

You can read about TWAIN and WIA E.g. from ["What are the differences between TWAIN and WIA?"](https://www.dynamsoft.com/web-twain/docs/faq/difference-between-Twain-and-wia.html)

> TWAIN driver TWAIN is the most widely used protocol for physical document scanners.
> ...
> WIA refers to [Windows Image Acquisition](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wia/-wia-startpage), which is the still image acquisition platform in the Windows family.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1164883)

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same problem and figured out two solutions by using Adobe Acrobat Pro as follows:

1. Use Acrobat Pro to print (re-pdf) the scanned file to letter size. The "problem" with this solution is that the re-pdf'd file size could be a few times larger than original.
2. Use Acrobat Pro to resize the scanned pages with the “Crop Pages”. This is a better solution and it worked great (no file size increase) for me.
   Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey Tony K! It seems like you accidentally created two accounts here: [This one](https://superuser.com/users/1594099/tony-k) as well as [this one](https://superuser.com/users/1594648/tony-k). Please [go here](https://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts) to contact the admins of Super User to have them merge the accounts.